Steps to implement notifications in AspNetBoilerplate
I am using aspnetboilerplate framework, ASP.NET Core + Angular 18 sample code.
I tried implementing notifications, as mentioned in documentation, https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Notification-System
The notification are published (I can see those in background jobs table, and removed automatically by job service), but on Angular UI side I don't see any notifications.
I am trying to post systemwide notifications, so that it will be shown to all users , without any need to subscribe, see code below in ASP.NET Core Web API:
public async Task Notify(int type)
{
    LocalizableMessageNotificationData data = null;

    switch (type)
    {
        case 1:
            data = new LocalizableMessageNotificationData(new LocalizableString("LowDiskWarningMessage", "MyLocalizationSourceName"));
            data["remainingDiskInMb"] = 100;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (data == null)
        return;

    await _notificationPublisher.PublishAsync("System.LowDisk", data, severity: NotificationSeverity.Warn);
}

I have following code on Angular side, in src\app\app.component.ts file, but it never gets called.
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.renderer.addClass(document.body, "sidebar-mini");

    SignalRAspNetCoreHelper.initSignalR();

    abp.event.on("System.LowDisk", (userNotification) => {
      alert("abp.notifications.received");

      console.log(userNotification);

      abp.notifications.showUiNotifyForUserNotification(userNotification);

      // Desktop notification
      Push.create("AbpZeroTemplate", {
        body: userNotification.notification.data.message,
        icon: abp.appPath + "assets/app-logo-small.png",
        timeout: 6000,
        onClick: function () {
          window.focus();
          this.close();
        },
      });
    });

Am I missing anything?
